# Публикация приложения на Play Market

Tags: android, google-play

У меня такой вопрос, есть приложение на 3-х языках (англ., русский, украинский), можно ли как-то в Play Market при публикации сделать, чтобы, например, для англоговорящих приложение было видно на англ. языке (то есть название, описание и т.д.), для русскоговорящих - на русском и т.д.? Или можно только на 1 языке опубликовать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Видимо Вы никогда не пользовались консолью разработчика.

Там есть отдельная кнопка "Добавить перевод", по нажатию на которую откроется еще одна вкладка с формами для заполнения описания, скриншотов и прочего на необходимом Вам языке.

Как это работает для пользователя?

Когда пользователь открывает страничку с приложением в браузере или на мобильном устройстве, браузер или приложение отобразит контент на необходимом языке. Если такой язык отсутствует, то отобразится дефолтный язык (так же можно указать в консоли)

Comment: хорошо что входной билет 25 баксов... так бы маркет был бы похож на полигон